# How to reset an IEnumerator instance in below case

Tags: c#, .net

How to reset an IEnumerator instance in below case? (e.Reset() throws NotImplementedException)

```
    void Main()
    {
       IEnumerator<string> e = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" }.Select(o => o).GetEnumerator();

       while( e.MoveNext() ) 
       {
           Console.WriteLine( e.Current );
       }

       if( 
            //some condition
         ) 
       {
           e.Reset();

           while( e.MoveNext() ) 
           {
               //Do something else with e.Current
           }
       }

    }
```

Comment: Also: [Why the Reset() method on Enumerator class must throw a NotSupportedException()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468170/why-the-reset-method-on-enumerator-class-must-throw-a-notsupportedexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the 'implementation' of the method will look *something* like this:

```
public void Reset() {
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

For reference [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx):

> The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not
>   necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can
>   simply throw a NotSupportedException.

Where, in this case, the exception type used is a deviation of that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the explanation is this:

> The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not
>   necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can
>   simply throw a NotSupportedException.

and

> Notes to Implementers All calls to Reset must result in the same state
>   for the enumerator. The preferred implementation is to move the
>   enumerator to the beginning of the collection, before the first
>   element. This invalidates the enumerator if the collection has been
>   modified since the enumerator was created, which is consistent with
>   MoveNext and Current.